# XeTex - Times New Roman font for Romanian characters ș, ț, Ș and Ț

Tags: xetex, lyx, characters, extended-characters, times

I have downloaded the Times New Roman font and put it into `.local/fonts` where it should be (my OS is Fedora 17 and I use TexLive 2012). It is recognized by LibreOffice and LyX. LibreOffice displays correctly the Romanian characters `ș,ț,Ș,Ț` and even converting the LibreOffice document to pdf keeps them visible and rightly displayed, but when I write a document in LyX using Times New Roman and XeTex compilation, even though I see them in the input document, the pdf output displays four squares instead of the desired characters. I expected that, since the command `fc-list :lang=ro | Times` does not display anything, so it's an incompatibility between Times New Roman and Romanian language (which I can't explain since LibreOffice correctly displays the four characters). How can I solve this? Do I need a special Times New Roman font? I haven't found one, it's almost 2013 and there's no Times New Roman for the Romanian language used in LyX with XeTex :)

Comment: I'm not sure, but this might be relevant: http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/7348

Comment: LibreOffice (and most GUI applications) can fallback to a different font for characters missing from the requested font, XeTeX does not do that.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using an arbitrary Times New Roman font (of unknown quality) rather than TeX Gyre Termes, a free Times clone developed by the 'TeX community' (GUST plus money from others)? The TeX Gyre fonts are pretty good on accent coverage.

Comment: Can you add a minimal example of LaTeX code with which you get such a problem?

Comment: @Khaled Hosny - No, it is not the case. I didn't notice any difference between the four characters and the others when using Times New Roman. They are the same.

Comment: @egreg I've already posted that I used XeTex, not LaTex. What minimal example do you want? A snapshot of the four squares that appear instead of the `șțȘȚ` characters?

Comment: @JosephWright I think your solution is the most viable alternative, although I wanted to have the original Times New Roman. Maybe LyX will like to read the four Romanian characters in Times New Roman in the future.

Comment: @riderplus You can show the code generated by LyX on a minimal example, so we can examine it. There may be a problem in it.

Comment: This is what I get from the command line `Running: xelatex  "newfile2.tex" > /dev/null
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9998 (TeX Live 2013/dev)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./newfile2.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, polish,romanian, etc. (many other languages) loaded.


Running: xdg-open "newfile2.pdf"`

Comment: @riderplus There is no 'original Times New Roman' in the computer world. The font was originally designed in the era of hot metal, so all of the electronic versions are derivatives in this sense.

Comment: @JosephWright Ok, then send me a link to a Tines New Roman font supported by XeTex with `șțȘȚ` characters in LyX. I would really like to have it. I would even pay for it, I need to write my thesis in Times New Roman.

Comment: *Times, not Tines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by actually using a different type of Times New Roman font (with Romanian glyphs). Otherwhise Joseph Wright's suggestion of using the TeX Gyre Termes is a nice hack. Thank you for your help.

Comment: From a legal point this is dangerous. I hope you own a Windows license.

Comment: I have bought my computer (Acer Aspire One) with Windows 7 starter and I double-boot. I haven't shared the Windows 7 fonts with anyone, I kept them for private usage. Why would that be a legal issue?

Comment: I don't see how using TeX Gyre Termes is a "hack".

Comment: Ok maybe I didn't use the right term. I meant to say it's a nice and smart replacement for Times New Roman (that's what I understand by a "hack" - maybe in the old fashion, not as it is used nowadays by mass-media, referring to "hacking" instead of "cracking").

Comment: @riderplus: You describe something, that is only legal, if you own a copy of some Microsoft software (I forgot, it’s also installed with Office). IMO an according warning belongs into your answer. You can BTW edit this, as it is your’s (Oh, I see, you already did that!).